# PhpStorm: Auto-format with line breaker

Tags: php, formatting, phpstorm, psr-2

I'm working on a new project with existing sources. And the guy who's writte code used a weird format code. See bellow :

```
     public function analyzeCalcul 
                       (   $calcul
                         , $selection
                       ) {
    $pattern                 = "/[0-9".$this -> revertSymbol."?]+/" ;
    preg_match_all ($pattern, $calcul, $out) ;
    // on regarde les numeros de questions
    if (!count ($out)) {
      $OneErrorToAff         = ErrorModel::newError () ;
      $OneErrorToAff -> AffOneError
              (   __LINE__
                , __FILE__
                , __CLASS__
                , "pattern pour le calcul de facette non trouvé ???"
              ) ;
      throw new Exception ($OneErrorToAff -> getStrError ()) ;
    }
   }
```

For my opinion, is not human readable, to many line breaker it's insane :O
I want format it in PSR 2, I can do it one file by file but the project is kind of big so I'm looking for an automation of it.

I tried many online tools but only file by file. 
I used PhpStorm, and I don't see any tricks for thoose line breaker.

Any suggestion about it ?

Comment: `Code | Reformat Code...`. If you invoke it from Project View panel, then this action will be applied to the selected files / whole folder.

Comment: Actual PSR-2 code style can be set at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP` -- there is `Set from...` link on right top side of the screen.

Comment: thanks for your help. 
I've already checked in code style, it's not working for line breaker. I haven't see anything about that. I can only manage space, tab...
Even if i fix psr-2 on the set form button.

Comment: It works with line breaks. Maybe you have `Keep when reformatting | Line breaks` checked? Please share your code style + 1 file that needs to be formatted (full file, share a link, not just copy-paste here)

Comment: Oh thanks LazyOne, I have'nt see it, i'm blind ... 
Thanks a lot ! you save to me many hours :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Code | Reformat Code...` for your code formatting needs.

If invoked from the Project View panel, this action will be applied to the selected files / whole folder.

---

Actual PSR-2 code style can be set at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP` -- there is `Set from...` clickable text on right top side of the screen.

**P.S.** Ensure that your have `Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | Line breaks` option disabled.